# How to filter a model on tha basis of Column Format in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

I have been struggling with a Client request to filter out A model(Candidate) on the basis of Column Format

The issue I am facing is that column inputs either SSN or EIN.
The format for SSN is (xxx-xx-xxxx)
The format for EIN is (xx-xxxxxxx)

My candidates Table contains the field ssn_or_ein , which takes either one of these 2.

For ex:
candidate111.ssn_or_ein => 111-11-1111
candidate222.ssn_or_ein => 22-2222222

I have tried fetching all the 4000 accounts, but i suppose that's not how a developer's approach should be.

I am still learning Rails and any tip would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find people only with an EIN? And people only with an SSN?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. There is a new stripe updates which disallows EIN. So We want to update the chunk of people who have entered EIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [like](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) query. Put it in a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) so it's easily available.

```
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
  scope with_ein -> { where( "ssn_or_ein like ?", "__-_______" }
  scope with_ssn -> { where( "ssn_or_ein like ?", "___-__-____" }
end
```

However, this can get slow if `ssn_or_ein` is not properly indexed.

---

Consider storing them in two different columns. This makes validation and querying simpler. Bring them together only when you just need a [TIN - Taxpayer Information Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxpayer_Identification_Number).

```
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
  scope with_ein -> { where.not( ein: nil ) }
  scope with_ssn -> { where.not( ssn: nil ) }

  EIN_RE = %r{^\d{2}-\d{7}$}
  SSN_RE = %r{^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$}
  validates :ein, format: { with: EIN_RE }, allow_nil: true
  validates :ssn, format: { with: SSN_RE }, allow_nil: true

  def tin
    ssn || ein
  end

  class << self
    def find_by_tin(tin)
      where( ssn: tin ).or( where(ein: tin) )
    end
  end
end
```

I would also suggest that you store the data "normalized", without the dashes, just the numbers. This is simpler to work with, and the accepted format can be changed without having to change all the data. Format them in a [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
That worked fine and I was able to fetch SSS candidates:
`c_ssn = Candidate.where("ssn_or_ein like ?", "%___-__-____%")`
and then i was able to map the required colums

However, for EIN, I the records fetched were a mix of both EIN and SSN 
So, I figured out that every EIN started with 8 and this did the job

`c_ein = Candidate.where("ssn_or_ein like ?", "%8_-_______%") `

I want to figure out a way to filter EIN wihtout adding 8 as the prefix, for future requirement

Comment: @shashankbarman You should not have needed to add `%` to the like query unless there is something more in the ssn_or_ein field than you're telling us.

Comment: Yes, % wasn't required. Thanks for the insight Senpai